# HttpClient properties not being passed with DI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, dotnet-httpclient, .net-5

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core 5.0 project which has a service that accesses an API.
Based on the code below, I'd expect the HttpClient supplied to ToornamentService's constructor to contain the declared BaseAddress and API key header.

However, when debugging, I noticed that the HttpClient never has either of those. BaseAdress is null, and the header is missing.
I've tried using an IHttpClientFactory instead of the typed client, but I end up with the same result.

What am I doing wrong?

ConfigureServices Method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //Omitted for brevity
        services.AddHttpClient<ToornamentService>(c =>
        {
            c.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.toornament.com/");
            c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Api-Key", Configuration["Toornament:ApiKey"]);
        });

        services.AddTransient<ToornamentService>();
    }
```

ToornamentService class:

```
public ToornamentService(HttpClient client)
    {
        Client = client; // client.BaseAddress here is null
    }
```

Comment: Did you have a look at Microsoft's example here ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Remove this line: `services.AddTransient<ToornamentService>();`

When you call `AddHttpClient`, it registers the service *for you* as transient.

So what you are doing is registering it twice. And since your transient registration is the last registration, that takes precedence over the `AddHttpClient` registration.

Comment: In case you want to IoC: `services.AddHttpClient<IService, Implementation>( ...` API would help.