# Typed HttpClient injected into service without config defined in Startup.cs

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-5

Im trying to use a Typed HttpClient for my .net 5 project. Im setting up the HttpClients like this...

```
services.AddHttpClient<IMyService, MyService>(client =>
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(applicationSettings.MyServiceUrl);
                client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(60000);
            });
```

Then im getting it in my service via DI like this...

```
public class MyService : IMyService {
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

        public MyService(HttpClient httpClient)
        {
            _httpClient = httpClient;
        }
       
        public async Task<object> PostItemAsync(Request request)
        {
           return await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);
        }

}
```

but my issue is that when i go to use the HttpClient it doesn't have my BaseAddress or Timeout set. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I replicated your code and It works for me, is it the only one typed `HttpClient` you register?

Comment: Make sure you aren't doing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66641980/httpclient-properties-not-being-passed-with-di).

Comment: @Andy i was totally doing that. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the comments on my above post, @Andy pointed me to this [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66641980/httpclient-properties-not-being-passed-with-di) which pointed out that AddHttpClient registers a Transient Instance of my Service Class. I was adding my own singleton instance later in my Startup file which was wrong. I removed my adding of the singleton and my issue was fixed!